# Can a phase transition in a volume of a material propagate faster than the speed of sound in this material?

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition

I have heard that the phase transition of a material for example liquid water to vapor or ice propagates faster (assuming it was initiated at critical point $t=0$) over the volume of the material than sound would have?

Is this true and why is this?

Any references about this in the literature?

Comment: A phase transition does not involve point-to-point causation. It only involves the existence of a global order parameter (like temperature, magnetic field etc.). The real problem in your question is the meaning of "phase transition". What is called a phase-transition in the theory is the global change of the order of the system as a function of the order parameter. It is NOT the motion of e.g. a melting or freezing surface of a water/ice mixture. As long as there is a two-phase system, the "phase transition" has simply not occurred, yet.

Answer (score 2):

Phase transition may occur simultaneously in many parts of material. In this sense, *propagation* does not imply *propagation of information* (or propagation of any kind of wave/excitation.)

Comment: Yes I agree with you general conlcusion but at the atomic scale phase transitions involve the speed of light interactions so therefore could we not say that phase transitions are happening at the speed of light in this material which is far more faster than the speed of sound?

Comment: @Markoul11 It definitely happens slower than the speed of light, since it involves physical changes, not just signal propagation. I was thinking more about something like a movement of domain walls, where spins flip one-by-one.

Comment: @Markoul11 Speaking of ferromagnets, Note also, that the nature of interactions associated with phase transition may have nothing to do with elasticity (i.e., sound.) In ferromagnetism critical fluctuations can be viewed as excitation of magnons - so speed of magnons is definitely the limiting factor. In hydrodynamics one can have potentially other types of waves, besides sound waves... but also convection - like rising of bubbles, whose speed perhaps may be faster than the speed of sound (supersonic bubbles?)

Comment: I see. I was thinking when I edited the question in a more fundamental way. Anyway thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: @Markoul11 I would suggest thinking it over and asking more specific question.  As long as your questions are clearly formulated and get some positive score, asking more does not harm.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of sound is undefined around a phase transition as it is typically different in different phases. So there is certainly no fundamental limit on information propagating faster.